# Kentico Personas Update time Delay

Tags: c#, kentico

We are using Kentico inbuilt personas for one of our web sites and we are experiencing about five seconds delay when updating personas. We have some contact fields and we use rules to set personas. Is there any way to improve the persona's update time. We use the following code snippet to update the contact:

```
int contactId = ModuleCommands.OnlineMarketingGetCurrentContactID();
Dictionary<string, object> contactData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
contactData.Add("key", "Test");
ModuleCommands.OnlineMarketingUpdateContactFromExternalSource(contactData, true, contactId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to update contact in Kentico is to use `ContactInfoProvider` class like this:

```
    var contact = ContactInfoProvider.GetContactInfo(OnlineMarketingContext.CurrentContactID);

    if (contact != null)
    {
        // update contact
        contact.ContactFirstName = "Arnold";
        contact.SetValue("CustomField", "Value");

        // save contact
        contact.Update();
    }
```

This code updates the contact directly in database and there is no delay in updating the contact.

To ensure the recalculation of the personas/contact groups you can use the following web.config key:

```
<add key="CMSProcessContactActionsInterval" value="1" />
```

Kentico by default stores the activities/contact updates in memory and then processes them every 10 seconds, by changing it to 1 you should see the changes much faster. Keep in mind that this is not recommended for high traffic sites with lots of activities being logged all the time. The reason is that the activities need to be logged into DB and you don't want to keep hitting your DB all the time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is bit faster now. Contact updates immediately and takes few second to update personas. As i mention in the question we use rules to update personas. I think main issue is it takes while to update personas from the rule. Is there any way to improve the persona update time from rule.

Comment: Hey, see the new comment. The way you can make the processing faster is by using the "<add key="CMSProcessContactActionsInterval" value="1" />" web.config key. Hope it helps!